# Hazelcast Near Cache

Tags: hazelcast

I have a setup of two node hazelcast 3.2 with each node containing 500 MB of data.I have configured client side Near cache.

**I have following questions**

1. How to verify that data is fetched from near cache hashmap?
2. Some of my maps have only one entry i.e., size=1, which sometimes on
   heavy load takes 20 to 30 ms to fetch the data?
3. The time taken on heavy load is between 4ms to 20 ms.If it is
   fetching from near cache,what will be the optimal fetch time in
   millisecond.
4. What is the best GC policy to be set on the server?

**My server side config**

```
mapCfg = new MapConfig();
mapCfg.setName("TL_MAP_2");
mapCfg.setBackupCount(1);
mapCfg.setReadBackupData(true);//enabled as it is sync backup
mapCfg.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY);
cfg.addMapConfig(mapCfg);
```

**My client side code is a singleton**

```
public enum CacheService {
    INSTANCE;

    private static ClientConfig clientConfig = null;
    private static HazelcastInstance cacheClient = null;
    private static Set<String> nearcaches = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("TL_MAP_1","TL_MAP_2","TL_MAP_3","TL_MAP_4","TL_MAP_5","TL_MAP_6","TL_MAP_7","TL_MAP_8","TL_MAP_9","TL_MAP_10"));

    static{

        if(clientConfig ==null || cacheClient ==null){

        clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:5701","XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:5702").setSmartRouting(true);;


        clientConfig.setExecutorPoolSize(120);
        Iterator<String> iterator = nearcaches.iterator();
        String near = null;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            near = iterator.next();
            clientConfig.addNearCacheConfig(near, new NearCacheConfig().setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT));
        }


        cacheClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        }
    }

    public HazelcastInstance getCacheClient(){
        return cacheClient;
    }

    public Map get(String cacheName) {

        Map cacheMap = cacheClient.getMap(cacheName);

    if (nearcaches.contains(cacheName)) {

            NearCacheStats stats = ((IMap) cacheMap).getLocalMapStats()
                    .getNearCacheStats();
            logger.info("Near Cache HITS for map " + cacheName + "  ::"
                    + stats.getHits());
        }


        return cacheMap;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you solved your issues? can you share the answers?

Answer (score 0):

For #1 if it's fetch from near cache the latency will be 0ms.